# How to do within group moderation analysis without subsetting data

Tags: r, mediation

Let's say I run the following regression specification:

```
lm(outcome ~ treatment)
```

Where treatment is a factor variable that can take four values `A, B, C, or D` . I suspect that there is this predictor, `X` that moderates the relationship between the treatment and the outcome.  However, I don't really care about comparisons across treatment groups -- what I want to be able to say is that, within a given treatment (e.g. `A`), people with high values of `X` have better outcomes then individuals with low values of `X`.

What comes to mind is some kind of interaction effect like:

```
lm(outcome ~ treatment*X)
```

But that will only tell me how the treatment varies at different levels of X, in comparison to some left out reference group (rather than in comparison to the same treatment but low values of X).

What is the right way of going about doing this?

---

Edit: Ran the nested specification suggested by @cdtip and it resulted in the following output:

```
             Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper  DF
(Intercept)   -1.33113   4.96200 -0.26826 0.7889642 -11.1572  8.49498 118
treatmentC    -5.90437   6.94422 -0.85026 0.3969036 -19.6558  7.84706 118
treatmentB    24.92750   9.27155  2.68860 0.0082136   6.5673 43.28769 118
treatmentA    7.26947    5.73785  1.26693 0.2076739  -4.0930 18.63197 118
treatmentD:X  0.65245    1.27021  0.51366 0.6084530  -1.8629  3.16782 118
treatmentC:X  5.15284    1.64776  3.12717 0.0022231   1.8898  8.41586 118
treatmentB:X -2.65812    1.08513 -2.44959 0.0157709  -4.8070 -0.50927 118
treatmentA:X -0.69822    0.67031 -1.04163 0.2997141  -2.0256  0.62919 118
```

I'm somewhat unclear how to interpret this.  The coefficient on `treatmentC:X` is `5.15` and significant.  But it seems like it's significant relative to the left out condition which is `treatmentD`, rather than making a within treatment comparison.  How am I supposed to interpret these results?

It seems like the `/` operator is just shorthand for:

```
lm(outcome ~ treatment + treatment:x)
```

(so removing the main effect of X).

I have found references to "subgroup analysis" and "heterogeneous treatment effect", but these seem to refer to a singular treatment condition, in which the size of the effect varies by some moderator.

---

EDIT: In order to test the overall moderating effect of the moderate `X` I've conducted a Wald Test like so:

```
library(estimatr)
library(lmtest)
m1 <- lm_robust(outcome ~ treatment / X - 1, data = data)
m2 <- lm_robust(outcome ~ treatment - 1, data = data)
waldtest(m1, m2)

Wald test

Model 1: outcome ~ treatment/X - 
    1
Model 2: outcome ~ treatment - 1
  Res.Df Df Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1    640                        
2    644 -4  18.9    0.00084 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

How do I interpret this?  I assume this is evidence that of an overall moderating effect of X, but how do I interpret `18.9`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want is to avoid reference cell coding. You want a slope and intercept for the effect of `X` on `outcome` at each level of `treatment`. You need to modify @cdtip's code to exclude an intercept, and you should get what you need:

```
lm(outcome ~ treatment/X - 1)
```

Now, each coefficient `treatmentA:X`, etc., is the effect of `X` on the outcome for those in treatment A. By removing the intercept, you get a slope for each treatment level. To test whether there is an overall moderating effect of `X`, you can use `anova()` to compare the above model with a model that excludes `X` (but is otherwise the same); a significant p-value indicates the presence of moderation.

---

In response to question edits:

This parameterization essentially creates 4 separate regression models of `outcome` on `X`, one for each treatment group, but estimated together in a single model. The "main effects" are the intercepts of each treatment group-specific regression. They are not treatment effects. Treatment effects would be comparisons between these intercepts, which represent the difference in the treatment group means when `X` is 0. The interaction terms are interpreted simply as the slopes of each treatment group-specific regression. So from this coefficient table, you can describe the slope and intercept of the regression of `outcome` on `X` in each treatment group. This parameterization does not allow you to make any comparisons between treatment groups, but it is possible to reparameterize to get the contrasts you want, if any.

Comment: Just to be clear.  With this specification, if I see a significant effect on an interaction term that implies that, within that treatment, the moderator was significantly predictive of the outcome?

Comment: Also do you have a sense of how to test the overall effect of `X` with cluster-robust standard errors?  I'm using `lm_robust` for clustering, and it doesn't look like anova is compatible

Comment: Your clarification statement is correct. If you are willing to migrate to the `survey` package, the functions there are compatible with `anova()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Noah!  Do you mind taking one last look at my edits?  I'm having trouble making sense of the main effects.  Are the main effects just uninterpretable in light of the interactions?  Can I interpret the interactions without reference to the main effects?  If not, is there a way to make the interactions interpretable on their own?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I need to wait 17 hours to approve the bounty.  Appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Does removing the intercept force all regression lines to an origin at {0,0} and make a worse model overall for what appears to be a continuous outcome?

Comment: No. With only categorical predictors, a fully saturated model is just estimating subgroup means. As long as as many coefficients are being estimated as there are means, the fit of the model will be identical, regardless of the parameterization. In R, when you remove an intercept in the presence of a categorical predictor, an extra coefficient is estimated to account for what would have been the reference category, so the same number of coefficients is estimated either way. With continuous predictors, however, your worry is valid.

Comment: Appears that the OP does have a continuous response variable. The significance has increased which is, I believe, almost expected when removing the intercept.

Comment: @Noah, "X" is a continuous predictor. Should I be worried, then?  Based upon what Todd mentioned

Comment: No, if both predictors were continuous there would be a problem, but not with continuous `X` and a categorical moderator.

Comment: @Noah  Nearly one year later, I'm still at this.  I had a question for you.  I'm trying to test whether there is an "overall moderating" effect of X using the anova approach you described. However, as mentioned ANOVA doesn't work with robust models, and I was cautioned against using them because they rely strongly on the assumption of variance homogeneity, and the test statistics are basically likelihood ratio tests.  

I instead was pointed in the direction of wald tests.  I now run two models:
`fit_1 <- lm(outcome ~ treatment/X - 1)` and `fit_2 <- lm(outcome ~ treatment- 1)`

Comment: And I use `waldtest(fit_1, fit_2)` from the `library(lmtest)`  the resulting p-value is highly significant with a Chi. Sq of 18.09.  I'm not entirely sure if this is achieving the same thing you described with Anova, and I'm not sure how to interpret the 18.09.  Do you have any thoughts?  I've included output in a new edit above.

Comment: `waldtest` does the same thing as `anova` for linear models as long as you set `test = "F"`, so that is a valid method. `waldtest` is compatible with `lm_robust` models, too, if you feel comfortable using them. Otherwise, with `lm` models, you can supply `waldtest` with a function to extract robust standard errors. `waldtest(fit_1, fit_2, type = "F", vcov = function(x) sandwich::vcovHC(x, type = "HC2")` with `lm` objects will give the same results as `waldtest` on `lm_robust` objects.

Comment: The p-value on the test indicates whether there is evidence that the coefficients that differ between the full and reduced models are jointly equal to zero, indicating that that the moderator has neither a main effect nor an interaction with the treatment on the outcome. Rejecting the null hypothesis means that the moderator does play some role. You can also think of it as testing whether the change in $R^2$ from the reduced to full model is different from zero.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding right, you may be wanting to do an analysis of covariance (ANCOVA). There is a helpful tutorial here (http://r-eco-evo.blogspot.com/2011/08/comparing-two-regression-slopes-by.html).

Specifically, read down to the bottom where comparing slopes and intercepts is discussed. This was achieved through a slightly different version of your code.

```
lm(outcome ~ treatment/x) # assuming x is a continuous predictor
```

Because of the nested design, you are essentially only comparing the values of x within their respective treatments.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much!  This certainly seems like the right direction.  Could you take a look at my edit?  I'm not sure how to make sense of the resulting values.